# Facebook share posted only in my wall not in my friends wall - ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I intended to post (Image or String or Link) in Facebook. When i tried to post with the following code it is only posting in my wall, not showing in my friends wall.

Permission :

"read_stream","publish_stream","email","user_birthday","friends_about_me","friends_activities","friends_likes".

```
 - (IBAction)fblogin:(id)sender {

     AppDelegate *getdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

     getdelegate.facebook.sessionDelegate=self;

     Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

     NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];



     if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {

        if([getdelegate.facebook isSessionValid])

        {

            NSLog(@"User already logined with facebook");

        }

        else

        {

            [getdelegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"publish_stream",@"email",@"user_birthday",@"friends_about_me",@"friends_activities",@"friends_likes",nil]];

        }

    }

    else

    {

        NSLog(@"No Internet Connection");

    }

    }



    - (void)fbDidLogin

    {

    AppDelegate *getdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [getdelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];

}



- (void) request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result

{

    AppDelegate *getdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])

    {


    }
}



- (IBAction)Sharebutton:(id)sender

{

    AppDelegate *getdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSLog(@"TOKEN:%@",getdelegate.facebook.accessToken);



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage *img= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:img,@"picture",@"http://www.google.com",@"link",@"Message text",@"message",nil];

    [[getdelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"

                                       andParams:params

                                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"

                                     andDelegate:self];



}
```

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Read this link changed in Facebook Methods

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

IdOfFriend/Feed method wont work anymore

Read it for more help:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Answer (score 0):

```
[[getdelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"

                                       andParams:params

                                   andHttpMethod:@"POST"

                                     andDelegate:self];
```

instead of "me/feed" you have to provide the facebook id of the friend on whose wall you want to share.

Comment: i need share all my friends in same time